# Modifying XSD schema - Adding new element is greyed out

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xsd, visual-studio-2003

I would like to modify my XSD schema to add a new element but that option is greyed out.  Only adding a new relation or key is available.  How can I do this via the schema diagram?

[image]

Comment: Sure, http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/403/ss001n.jpg/

Comment: Is the schema file read only?

Comment: Nope. The xsd, xsx and wsdl files are definitely read and write.

Comment: I've tried debugging and not debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.  I reopened Visual Studio as Administrator and it resolved.  I think changing the security of the encapsulating directory and/or schema.cs might also resolve this, but like I said, I went with running VS as Admin.